# How to clean a muffler from the inside?

Tags: motorcycle, cleaning, two-stroke, muffler

I want to clean the muffler (final exhaust pipe) of my motorcycle (2004 Cagiva Raptor 125). It is a 2 stroke engine so a bit of oil has sort of... sedimented on the inside of it. How am i supposed to clean it? It is made out of stainless steel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean just the end section then a cleaning fluid, wire brush / wire wool and large amounts of elbow grease aka effort.

If you have a drill mounted wire brush that will fit is another option.